# How to add the additional column that contains the list of values?

Tags: sql-server-2008

1) I have a query that writes the list of actions to temp table1:

```
declare @table1 table (ActionName varchar(250), ActionDate datetime, ... Description varchar(100))

insert into @table1(ActionName, ActionDate, ... Description)
select --Search actions by ActionName
```

The actions can have multiple action dates, which is important and it means we can have multiple records with the same action name, but different action dates.

2) I have to reduce table1 to get all action names appears only once, but with additional field DateList (comma separated string) that should contain the list of all date actions (ActionDate field) for that action:

```
declare @table2 table (ActionName varchar(250), ActionDate datetime, ... Description varchar(100), DateList varchar(4000))
```

I know how to create the list of action dates:

```
declare @dateList varchar(4000)
select @dateList = coalesce(@dateList + ', ', '') + convert(varchar, ActionDate, 120)
from @temp
```

But, I'm not sure how to incorporate it in the whole solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your list-creation code in a function and then use that on your table like this:

```
insert into @table2
select ActionName, uf_GetDateList(ActionName)
from @table1
group by ActionName
```

Now the function itself is a tricky part. You need to pass the @table1 down there somehow. You can either turn @table1 into a temporary table #table1 then you would do something like this:

```
select @dateList = coalesce(@dateList + ', ', '') + convert(varchar, ActionDate, 120)
from #temp1
where ActionName=@ActionName
```

Or you can use [table-valued parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489(v=sql.100).aspx) to pass the table variable into the function.